# Check whether names(df) is in other character list giving both true and false values back

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following

```
structure(list(id = c(14, 15, 16, 17, 18), a = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 
6), b = c(3, NA, 2, 5, 7), c = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

  id a  b c
1 14 1  3 1
2 15 2 NA 2
3 16 3  2 3
4 17 5  5 4
5 18 6  7 5

library(caret)
corr <- cor(na.omit(df))
highcorr <- findCorrelation(corr, cutoff = 0.9, names=TRUE)

highcorr
[1] "a"  "id"
```

I would like to get a new data frame where if the col name is in highcorr returns true, else false. New data frame would look like this

```
  col   result
1 id    TRUE  
2 a     TRUE  
3 b     FALSE 
4 c     FALSE
```

I think I'm thinking way too difficult. I tried things with %in% but then you only get the TRUE values. Any suggestion would be appreciated :)!

Comment: `data.frame(col=names(df), result=names(df) %in% highcorr)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
a<-melt(corr,value.name = "corr") 
a<-a[!duplicated(a$corr),]
a<- a %>% select(Var1, corr)%>% mutate(result = ifelse(corr > 0.9,T,F )) %>% select(Var1, result)

  Var1  result
1   id  TRUE
2    a  TRUE
3    b FALSE
4    b FALSE
```